# DebuggerDisplay - type in square brackets

Tags: c#, .net, debuggerdisplay

```
class A
{
    public Color ColorA { get; set; }
    public Color ColorB { get; set; }

    public A(Color colorA, Color colorB)
    {
        ColorA = colorA;
        ColorB = colorB;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ColorA + " " + ColorB;
    }
}
```

This renders as:

[image]

---

And this:

```
class A
{
    public Color ColorA { get; set; }
    public Color ColorB { get; set; }

    public A(Color colorA, Color colorB)
    {
        ColorA = colorA;
        ColorB = colorB;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Red" + " " + "Black";
    }
}
```

renders as:

[image]

Why the difference?

Edit: I know why the difference. My question is, how to achieve second result without hardcoding the text of the color.

Comment: Try `return ColorA.ToString() + " " + ColorB.ToString();` the difference is likely due to the fact that it is calling ToString on the underlying type, ie `Color` in it's base implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return ColorA.Name + " " + ColorB.Name;
```

Answer (score 3):

The first method implicitly invokes `ToString` on the `Color` instances, while the second one is just you returning a string.

To your edit: I'm not sure, but I think it is done automatically. Otherwise, have a look into the `ToKnownColor` method, it returns a `KnownColor` enumeration, which you can use to construct a color with the behaviour you want. However, you should be aware of the fact that there won't be a name for every color possible.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's showing your ToString() result.

The first one calls Color.Red.ToString(), which gives 'Color [Red]', then Color.Black.ToString().

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, the ToString() method of the Color class is being called (giving the Color [ColorName] output).